# Youtube frame api - video doesn't play from start (IE + Chrome issue)

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, frame

I have an issue with the Youtube frame API.

My video has the ID `z1gTBVs6zsw`. I'm using the default Youtube example code ([here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=cs)) and my result is ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/gDMQY/50/)).

```
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'z1gTBVs6zsw',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

// 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}

// 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
//    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
var done = false;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
    done = true;
  }
}
function stopVideo() {
  player.stopVideo();
}
```

The problem is that the video starts in the IE10/9/8 and Chrome at 4 seconds. In Firefox it's OK. I have no idea where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. remove the videoId: 'z1gTBVs6zsw' from the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
2. replace onPlayerReady() with:

   ```
   function onPlayerReady(event) {
       player.loadVideoById("z1gTBVs6zsw");
   }
   ```